# Pass href value of anchor link to URL parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, href, anchor

I'm looking to pass the href value of an anchor into the address bar as a parameter when clicked i.e. ?url=xxxx.pdf. This is so it can be passed onto the next page and used in a hidden field on a form. I also need the default action on the anchor to change and direct to a different URL that contains the form with the hidden field (I can handle the form).

So i need to:

1. Click the anchor link
2. Append the destination to a URL parameter
3. Divert to the lead capture page (im guessing maybe after a couple of seconds to allow the browser time to append the url.

I have spent some time searching the web but can't find any info on this specific query, is anybody able to help?

Answer (score 0):

The best way will be to [modify location.search property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location#example_5_send_a_string_of_data_to_the_server_by_modifying_the_search_property) to achieve this

```js
document.querySelector('#test-anchor').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  location.search = this.href;
});
```

```html
<a id="test-anchor" href="url=xxxx.pdf">Test Anchor</a>
```

Comment: This is great i think i can get this working by adding the ?v= to all links on the page i'm working on. One last questions... how can i change the location from current page to a different url?

Comment: `location.href= "someurl" + this.href;` will do

Comment: Thanks, but this doesnt change the location and just reloads the same page still here is the code:

    <a href="?doc=Checklist.pdf">Test Anchor</a>

<script>
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  location.href= "https://xxxxxxx.com/apps/gated-content-form/" + this.href;
});
</script>